# Does cloudrun on GKE support websockets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

This is my first time using GCP, and I'm trying to put my project on production, and I'm running into problems with getting websocket communication working.  I've been googling around and I'm super unclear on if cloud run on GKE supports inbound/outbound websocket connections.  The limitations docs say that cloud run fully managed does not work with inbound websockets, but does not say anything about cloud run on gke having issues with websockets.

I can post my ingress config and stuff, not really sure what exactly is relevant to this, but I've just followed their getting setup guide so everything is still set to the default for the most part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. However, WebSockets do work outbound. This is a [known issue on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#grpc_websocket). You can use either just [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress?hl=es-419#support_for_websocket) or [App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity?hl=es-419) as recommended alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  So just so I'm 100% clear, GKE on cloudrun will not work with websockets, but standalone GKE will work?  If that is the case, I'll move my deployment over the just GKE and not use cloudrun for anything.

Comment: Hi, Kubernetes on Cloud may work, but there are known issues, so it's very likely that you will be getting errors 400 when your app scales to more than one pod. For now the safe way it's going straight to GKE.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, thanks for much for the help! <3

Comment: @ChristianGonzalez do you know when Cloud Run will support sockets?

Comment: @dendog there is no information on this. Don't even know if Cloud Run will support sockets in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer, as of January 2021, is yes!  You will need to use the beta api when deploying your service.  Details are here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-websockets-http-2-and-grpc-bidirectional-streams